# exporting java runtimes to matlab

Tags: java, matlab, file, type-conversion

I am looking for a method to export the execution time of a programm to matlab. I worked with copy/paste method so far ^^
I don't have any experience concerning file interactions with anything else than the console output. So thanks for detailed answers.

So what I imagine to do is storing the results in some matlab-compatible file but any other ideas are welcome.
The aim is basically to convert a java array to a matlab matrix.

I am using Eclipse.

Thanks for any help

Comment: This isn't clear. A text file is Matlab-compatible, why don't you just use that?

Comment: I can open a txt-file in matlab but then I can't (or don't know how to)convert it into a matlab variable so that I can plot it.

Comment: Take a look at textscan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution as mentioned by Daniel

1. Save your java results in a .txt file that looks like that:

   1 2 3

   4 5 6

   7 8 9
2. use textscan to convert it into a matlab variable

   file= fopen('whatever.txt')

   Variable=textscan(file,'%d %d %d')

Hoping this is useful to someone else. Any other ideas are welcome.